# Music on iPhone isn't visible in Google Play Music app

Tags: music, google

On my old Android device, I used Google Play Music. It would sync the music that was on my Android device (music app) into Google Play Music.

I synced MP3s using iTunes from my computer to my iPhone, but they don't show up in Google Play Music.

I don't enjoy switching from app to app just to listen to different music. Help?

Comment: I started to edit your question to put in a useful, concise title but realized I have no idea what you're trying to say or ask. What version of iOS are you using? When you say you "imported" most of your music to the iPhone music app, how did you do so - iTunes? - and where did it come from - your computer? music synced with Google Play Music? When you say "your library," do you mean the music on your iPhone or the music from your collection in Google Play Music?

Comment: Alright, so let's answer these, through my computer I synced my iPhone with mp3s on the computer, and after that happened they appeared on my Music app. After that I installed Google Play Music, I logged onto my Google account and then it synced up with my purchases, the mp3s were missing. I have no idea what IOS this is. The music was imported from my computer to ITunes and when I say my library I mean The Google play on my old android would go to the music app on my android and import those into it's own library, the Google music app doesn't seem to do that on my iPhone

Comment: Hopefully it was cleared up a tad bit

Answer (score 1):

I feel like what was actually happening on Android is that it was uploading files from your library to the cloud and then making them available in Google Play Music (one of its major features). It also could have been reading the music library on the device directly. I'm not completely sure, to be honest, but for purposes of this answer, it's mostly irrelevant.

For iOS, though, you will need to upload the music to Google Play Music using the [Google Play Music Manager](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075570?hl=en) on your computer. Once that's done it will be available on Google Play Music on your iOS device (and Android, for that matter).

Otherwise, you would need to use the iPhone Music app to listen to the MP3s you synced onto your iPhone, or another app that supports directly using those MP3s.